# docker private image can not be pulled in centos7

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I created a docker image and pushed to docker hub, then i changed it to private.
In my Mac, I can pull it after I issued "docker login" and entered all the info.
But in Cento7 (VM), this is no longer working, the private repository can not be found. I have to change the repo from private to public, then I can pull the image.
Why this happened? What do I need to do in order to pull a private repository from docker hub?
Thanks

Comment: do you have already pulled public version of this image?

Comment: Yes, @Cortwave, I have changed from private to public, then I can pull. After pulling, I have to change it back to private . This happened only in centos7.

Answer (score 0):

create a new file **.netrc** to

```
#vim .netrc
  machine github.com
      login < your github token >
```

Add those 2 lines and pass your github token

Then copy the **.netrc** file to the container by including this line in  dockerfile will pass credentials inside the docker containers and helps to pull more than one private repositories

```
COPY .netrc /root/
```